# Import huge json file into mongodb with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

i want to do a node.js script that goes through my mongo.db and checks if the url doesn't match with the url in my other database. As of right now, i have json with over 750k scam websites and i need to import it somehow to the database. Does anyone know any quick way to do it?
I tried:

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var link = require("./files/" + file);
    var newLink = new rescamdb({
      link: link,
      createdAt: Date.now(),
    });
    newLink.save();
    console.log(`
         Added new link to database
                  `);
  }
```

But it doesn't work, won't even create the database and then it fails on validation error.
The json file isn't mongodb ready, it looks like this:

```json
[
    "scamsite1.com",
    "scamsite2.com",
    "anotherscamsite.com",
    "scamsite4.com",
...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to share your model, and JSON file else it's hard to tell what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted my JSON so it looked like:

```json
[
{"link":"somescamwebsite.com"},
...
]
```

and then imported it to the mongo by mongoDB Compass

Comment: Are you still interested in a node.js script that will populate a database from a json file, or are you satisfied with using mongoDB compass to do this?